React component execution
React newbie here learning the ropes.
let guest = 0;

function Cup() {
  // Bad: changing a preexisting variable!  
  guest = guest + 1;
  console.log('Inside cup() before return - guest : '+guest); //added for info
  return <h2>Tea cup for guest #{guest}</h2>;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Cup />
      <Cup />
      <Cup />
    </>
  );
}

The above code prints

Tea cup for guest #2 
Tea cup for guest #4 
Tea cup for guest #6 

on the browser and console.log prints
Inside cup() before return - guest : 1 
Inside cup() before return - guest : 2 
Inside cup() before return - guest : 3 
Inside cup() before return - guest : 4 
Inside cup() before return - guest : 5 
Inside cup() before return - guest : 6 
Why does it print 2,4,6 instead of 1,2,3 ?
I can't understand how the body of the component method seems to execute six times though it is called only thrice in the component App.
What explains console.log printing six times in the above code when it should've printed only three times.
What am I missing here and which part of React documentation do I read to make sense of the above?

I removed React.StrictMode from index.js and it is finally behaving the way I intended it to. Question - Am I doing the right thing by removing React.StrictMode?

"The right thing" can be pretty subjective.  If you don't want to use it then removing it is the right way to do that.  I've personally always kept strict mode for development, it helps with testing and debugging things in the browser.

seeing the 2,4,6 instead of what you expected is pretty much exactly why strictmode behaves that way.  it reveals an issue with how you are managing the guest count (which i'm happy to see you already know is a problem).  react docs here

I found the explanation behind the behavior of methods getting called twice here - https://react.dev/learn/render-and-commit.  "When developing in “Strict Mode”, React calls each component’s function twice, which can help surface mistakes caused by impure functions."
